# Spinless Particle wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, spherical-harmonics

I've found wave function for spinless particle

$$\psi (r, \theta, \varphi)=N(x \pm y + 2z)\:e^{- \alpha r} $$

How do I find mean $\hat{L}^{2}$ and $\hat{L}_{z}$ in this state? I also wanted to calculate the probability of finding $\hbar$ measuring $\hat{L}_{z}$.

I know that I should normalize the angular part, but I don't know how. I'll be grateful for showing the method with a little commentary.

Comment: You can just take the representations of $L^2$ and $L_z$ in Cartesian coordinate (in terms of $x,y,z$ and $p_x, p_y, p_z$) and calculate the mean value. It's probably a bit tedious, but straightforward.

Comment: You *did* express your wavefunction in spherical coordinates and notice it is an eigenfunction of $\hat L^2$ with eigenvalue $2\hbar^2$, right? Did you expand it in spherical harmonics of l=1?

Comment: How to expand it in spherical harmonics of $l=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: in spherical coordinates, you [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#List_of_spherical_harmonics)
$$
\frac{1}{r}( 2z + x\pm y)= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}\Bigl (4 Y_1^0+\sqrt{2}\bigl (-(1\pm i)Y_1^1 +(1\mp i)Y_1^{-1}\bigr )~\Bigr );
$$
the orthonormality relation thereof over the unit sphere given in that link;
and the action of your operators on these pieces.

You can take it from here.